# PHP echo with if statement

Tags: php

I am trying to echo two different parts of HTML code based on the results from the if statement, which are again taken from the database. The number of results is not definite and it will vary based on the user input. It all works well except echoing the HTML. Here is the code:

```
<?php  
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT dt, soba1, soba2, soba3, soba4, soba5, soba6,     soba7, soba8, soba9, soba10 FROM calendar_table WHERE (dt BETWEEN '$dateFrom' AND '$dateTo')"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $date = $row['dt']; 
            $soba1 = $row['soba1'];
            $soba2 = $row['soba2'];
            $soba3 = $row['soba3'];
            $soba4 = $row['soba4'];
            $soba5 = $row['soba5'];
            $soba6 = $row['soba6'];
            $soba7 = $row['soba7'];
            $soba8 = $row['soba8'];
            $soba9 = $row['soba9'];
            $soba10 = $row['soba10'];

           echo " 
             <div class='column'> 
                <p class='dateBox'> $date </p>
                ". 
                    ( ($soba1 != NULL) ?
                      echo "<p class='status'> <input type='text' name='persons'> </p>"
                    :
                      echo "<p class='status'> $soba1 </p>"
                    ."  
                <p class='status'> $soba2 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba3 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba4 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba5 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba6 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba7 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba8 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba9 </p>
                <p class='status'> $soba10 </p>
              </div>"; 
            }; 
     ?>
```

Any suggestions on how this can be writen differently, or modified so that it works. THe error that i am getting is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\plazahotel\cro\confirm.php on line 137

Comment: You can't use echo within and echo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use following syntax:

```
 echo ($variableIsTrue ? 'Output A' : 'Output B');
```

But you have already an echo (starts at the DIV). You **Syntax is wrong**. Remove the unwanted echo's and add an `)`:

```
        <p class='dateBox'> $date </p>
            ". 
                ( ($soba1 != NULL) ?
                 "<p class='status'> <input type='text' name='persons'> </p>"
                :
                  "<p class='status'> $soba1 </p>"
                ) //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ADD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                ."  
            <p class='status'> $soba2 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `echo` call from within the ternary. You also are missing a closing `)`, so it becomes:

```
       echo " 
         <div class='column'> 
            <p class='dateBox'> $date </p>
            ". 
                (($soba1 != NULL) ?
                  "<p class='status'> <input type='text' name='persons'> </p>"
                :
                  "<p class='status'> $soba1 </p>")
                ."  
            <p class='status'> $soba2 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba3 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba4 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba5 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba6 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba7 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba8 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba9 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba10 </p>
          </div>";
```

Comment: Thanks in a million. I've been killing myself two days with this, and it was so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested `echo`, for the sake of easier reading, try:

```
<?php
echo "<div class='column'> 
      <p class='dateBox'> $date </p>";
if($soba1 != NULL){
      echo "<p class='status'> <input type='text' name='persons'> </p>";
}
else
{
      echo "<p class='status'> $soba1 </p> 
            <p class='status'> $soba2 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba3 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba4 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba5 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba6 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba7 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba8 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba9 </p>
            <p class='status'> $soba10 </p>
          </div>";
}
```

Comment: why do this? you can do it with ternary operator as MrCode shown. i.e. do it inline.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Like I said, there are too many quotes and dots + more quotes with semi-colon makes it harder to read.